# Domain wide localStorage fall-back for I6 & IE7?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

In our current project, we're using HTML 5 localStorage with fall-back to global storage for Firefox and userdata behaviors for IE6/IE7.
The fall-back is provided through a JS script called [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/).

This worked ok, until we started testing in IE6/IE7, even though it "works", it turns out that there's a restriction in userdata behaviour which locks it down so storage can only be set and read on the same URL or as MSDN puts it "For security reasons, a UserData store is available only in the same directory and with the same protocol used to [persist the store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)".

Hence if I set a value on one page and then navigate to another, although I'm on the same site, it won't work. 
Which for us pretty much renders it unusable as a fall-back for local storage, which is scoped per domain.

Has anyone come across this problem before and found a decent solution?
Any ideas or thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need IE6&7 support?

Comment: Good question, we're looking at the logs at the momnet to work out how, large percentage of the users are still on IE6/IE7. Unfortunately it looks like, probably yes, we do need it.

Answer (score 1):

Remy Sharp's polyfill will do that.

https://gist.github.com/remy/350433

Comment: While this link may answer the question, you should avoid link-only answers because links tend to decay over time.

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is to get data across two page in different paths, but *in the same domain*, you could try one of these (note: i didn't try: i'm just trying to be creative)

1. Use url rewriting (with an `.htaccess`) so you can access `/path1/page1` and `/path2/page2` with a single `path-rewritten/page1` and `path-rewritten/page2`
2. if you are in `/path2/page2` you could load an invisible iframe loading a page in `/path1` in which you get the data stored in some data structure that you pass in the parent document.
   Since page1 and page2 are - per hypothesys - in the same domain you can make the page1 and iframe communicate each other via javascript.

btw good question.

Answer (score 0):

A theoretical solution would be:

1. dynamically create a hidden "proxy" iframe accessing a static
   document retrieved from a location of your convenience, say
   http:/domain/proxy.html
2. proxy access to the DOM element in the iframe to persist/fetch data